# MODIFY to update a few specific fields of database table

Tags: abap, opensql

I would like to ask if it is possible to use `MODIFY` to update a few specific fields of database table.

I have made the below program just for this problem.

I found out that by using work area and looping throw internal table it is possible, but there has to be 2 `MODIFY` statements.

I would appreciate every answer.
Thansk guys.

```
REPORT ZTEST_MODIFY.

tables: zdegust.

data: it_zdegust type table of zdegust,
      lv_zkat like zdegust-zkat,
      lv_zvzor like zdegust-zvzor.
     
select * from zdegust into table it_zdegust.

lv_zvzor = 'test case'.
lv_zkat = '1'.

modify zdegust from it_zdegust TRANSPORTING zkat zvzor 
    where   lv_zvzor ne it_zdegust-zvor  
      and   lv_zkat  ne it_zdegust-zkat.
```

Comment: `MODIFY` is to update ALL the fields of the updated table or view. Two classic workarounds: either use `UPDATE` to maintain specifically some fields or create an updatable view in the ABAP Dictionary with only the fields you're interested in. Another solution is to use HANA SQLScript (not ABAP) through AMDP.